# Issue on adding Style to Manu Paths in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

Using Raphael.js I have a Paper with 250 path (called map). They all present on the paper but on styling I have some issue. I used

```
map.attr({fill: "grey",stroke: '#FFF','stroke-width': .5});
```

to style all paths but it only stylize the first path!? here is the way I generate the papaer

```
var map = paper.path(["M466.32309,424.29005L465.84309,424.29005 L465.36309423.33012L465.60309,z"]); 
var map = paper.path(["M453.60301,407.97121L454.08301,408.93114 L454.08301,407.73122L455.52302,408.21119L45.00303,410.61102 ,z"]); 
var map = paper.path(["M435.84289,397.65193L435.60289,397.65193 L435.84289,397.89192L435.84289,397.65193L436.32289,z"]);

map.attr({fill: "grey",stroke: '#FFF','stroke-width': .5});
```

Can you please let me know how to loop through all of pathes and add same style to all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't look quite right. You are overwriting 'map' each time, so I would assume its actually the last path that gets styled ?

Few possible options spring to mind.

1) You could push each element into a Raphael set. [(Raph set docs here)](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set). Then you could apply the style to the set (this would apply it to each element). Later you can traverse the set if you need to do anything else to it as well, like adding handlers.

2) You could possibly give each element a class, and then style that ? Or even apply a style to every path element, as you go, depending on the situation.

3) You could store each element of map in an array mapArray, which you can then traverse over with a traditional loop. This feels a bit clunkier, but should still work fine.

It would be useful to include an example in a jsfiddle, to get a more specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. Same principle than Ian "1°)" but i would add a function that does all the work, since it looks you're overwriting map 250 times.

```
            var momentaryPath;
            var arrayTotal;
            var paper = Raphael("paper1", 1060,610);
            arrayTotal=paper.set();  

            function map(path){
              momentaryPath=paper.path(path);
              arrayTotal.push(momentaryPath);
            }

            function draw(){

                      map("M10 10 l150 150 v150 l150z");
                      map("M350 350 l-150 -150 v-50z");

                      arrayTotal.attr({fill: "grey",stroke: '#FFF','stroke-width': .5});
           }
            draw();
```

With a function you could also chose to change the color of each path with an string in argument. Something like this :

```
 function map(path,color){
              momentaryPath=paper.path(path).attr({fill : color});
              arrayTotal.push(momentaryPath);
            }
```

You could also set a basic color and eventually change it, that's your choice.
Hope that helped :)